# Preguntas sin investigación y con respuesta aceptada ¿Deben permanecer abiertas o cerradas?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta

El día de hoy intente mejorar una pregunta del sitio principal, la cual también le asigne mi voto de cierre por demasiado amplia(no lo recuerdo muy bien), pregunta en cuestión es la siguiente: [Ejecutar función si se vacía un textarea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/74775/6635), la cual le puse como comentario al OP lo siguiente:

> Hola no eres un usuario nuevo, lo cual ya sabes como se pregunta por
>   aquí te invito a mirar nuevamente Cómo preguntar y también procura
>   agregar un Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

El me respondió el comentario diciendo algo así *(el comentario fue eliminado)*:

> ¿como puedo poner un ejemplo cuando ni siquiera tengo idea de como hacerlo?

proseguí [invitándolo a realizar una búsqueda en Google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74775/ejecutar-funci%c3%b3n-si-se-vac%c3%ada-un-textarea#comment137489_74775).

> como puedo poner ejemplos: ¿Qué investigación has hecho?, en Google
>   puedes encontrar información básica, como dice en Cómo preguntar
>   "Busca e investiga", tus búsquedas se pueden volver un ejemplo aunque
>   no funcione

Después vuelvo a entrar y veo que mi voto ha sido retirado, veo el timeline y aparece que fue cerrada por un moderador y reabierta.

Platicando por el chat con el moderador me comenta:

> la cerré porque lo que le pusiste tiene bastante sentido sin embargo
>   la reabrí porque vi que tenía respuestas y una de ellas ya estaba
>   aceptada.

No estoy del todo de acuerdo con lo que me responde, debido a que he visto preguntas muy similares y terminan cerradas aunque tengan respuesta aceptada. un ejemplo puede ser esta: [Validar campos vacios C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51330/6635), entre otras que no encuentro.

Answer (score 6):

El estado de una pregunta debe ser independiente de si se solucionó el tema o no. Si es demasiado amplia, lo seguirá siendo a pesar de que tenga respuestas.

Creo que es importante ser consistentes en nuestra gestión de cerrado de preguntas. Si tenemos unas líneas maestras, sigámoslas. De esta forma se evitará caerá en agravios comparativos (*¿Por qué me cierran esta si aquella otra no se cerró?* y demás).

Probablemente lo más pertinente aquí sería:

- Cerrarla como demasiado amplia, porque lo es.
- Dejarla visible (no borrarla<sup>1</sup>, vaya) porque el contenido parece ser útil.

Así trasladamos a los futuros usuarios la idea de que ese tipo de preguntas necesitan mejor enfoque.

Pero esperemos a ver qué comenta el moderador, pues lo mismo pasé algo por alto :)

---

<sup>1</sup>: La pregunta no será borrada de forma automática pues la respuesta ha sido aceptada y cuenta con varios votos positivos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero hay que hacer una puntualización. Hay un caso en que las respuestas sí influyen en que una pregunta merezca o no cierre: una pregunta sin trabajo de investigación sí es aceptable y no merece ser cerrada si es autorespondida.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos estoy bastante de acuerdo, a pesar de que [en general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/1983854) se recomienda que las preguntas cumplan los estandares de calidad independientemente de si es autorrespondida o no.

Comment: La pregunta tiene que ser interesante, bien formulada, concreta, dentro del ámbito del sitio, útil, clara, y con todos los elementos necesarios para responderla independientemente de si es autorrespondida o no. Pero no necesita trabajo de investigación y tampoco se debe recomendar trabajo de investigación en una pregunta autorrespondida.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos me gusta como planteas, comparto tu enfoque.