# ¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta-canónica

Veo que (al menos en [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)) proliferan preguntas como:

- [Diferencias entre continue y break en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/76865/83)
- [¿Para qué sirve `<?=` en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75296/83)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre echo, print, print_r, var_dump y var_export en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/83)

En todas ellas el autor realiza un enunciado muy claro pero sin aportar ningún tipo de investigación.

Sin ningún tipo de duda, son preguntas cuyas buenas respuestas serán muy útiles y a buen seguro generarán muchísimas visitas para el sitio. Sin embargo, las preguntas en sí no cumplen el mínimo de búsqueda, prueba, error que intentamos pedirle a todas.

El otro día Jose Antonio Dura Olmos me [comentaba](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2098/preguntas-sin-investigaci%C3%B3n-y-con-respuesta-aceptada-deben-permanecer-abiertas/2103#comment6440_2103):

> La pregunta tiene que ser interesante, bien formulada, concreta, dentro del ámbito del sitio, útil, clara, y con todos los elementos necesarios para responderla independientemente de si es autorrespondida o no. Pero no necesita trabajo de investigación y tampoco se debe recomendar trabajo de investigación en una pregunta autorrespondida.

Y estoy bastante de acuerdo. Por tanto, entendería preguntas así de genéricas si el autor la responde al mismo tiempo. Observemos el fantástico ejemplo de Pikoh de ayer mismo: [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/83), con una respuesta extensísima traducida del sitio en inglés.

Sin embargo, aquí estamos ante un caso distinto: alguien lanza una pregunta genérica y no muestra trabajo de investigación. Otros usuarios corren a contestar y se corre el riesgo de tener dos o tres buenas respuestas, la suma de las cuales sería fantástica.

¿Qué deberíamos hacer con estas preguntas? ¿Corremos el riesgo de intentar crear un [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) mediante preguntas-respuestas, en lugar de crear preguntas-respuestas en base a problemas reales?

Comment: Algunas de esas preguntas son tan tan básicas, que tengo la sensación (puedo estar equivocado) que se han creado con la mera intención de obtener votos positivos. Una simple búsqueda lo hubiera solucionado.

Comment: Pues si al final el objetivo de este sitio es crear contenido de calidad relacionado con la programación y desarrollo, esas preguntas, chuecas, incompletas y sin "mostrar investigación" contribuyen a este objetivo. Al final, el contenido de calidad es el binomio pregunta/respuestas. Ya ni modo. Que una buena respuesta nos salve de una mala pregunta.

Comment: @OscarR el problema es que si la pregunta básica no esta aquí, entonces google envía a los usuarios a OTROS SITIOS.. y esto BAJA NUESTRO SEO. lo que significa menos visitas y nos aleja de la meta de ser el sitio de referencia en programación en español... en mi humilde opinion, todas las preguntas tienen cabida aquí, por mas básicas que sean.

Comment: @EmanuelVe nótese que dije _básicas_ pero mi punto es "preguntas sin ningún tipo de investigación". Yo defiendo que lo más simple pueda ser resuelto aquí, pero siempre y cuando el autor muestre esfuerzo.

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo eso, lo comparto en un 90%, pero quería traer a la discusión el objetivo de la comunidad: Llegar y permanecer arriba en la lista de google cuando la búsqueda la hace un usuario que google sabe el español es su lengua madre. Si olvidamos el objetivo y nos ponemos a discutir sobre quien gano reputación ¨injusta¨, creo estamos distrayéndonos en bobadas-

Comment: @fedorqui, creo que el problema es que _"mostrar esfuerzo"_ es algo subjetivo. Mira esta [guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), punto 1. Menciona tres requisitos bien objetivos. Esto significa que la definición de estos requisitos es la misma para todos, sin interpretaciones personales y sin ambigüedades. Si se trata de establecer políticas generales para el tratamiento de preguntas básicas, lo ideal sería que se definan en consenso  dichos requisitos. Si solo se trata de esas tres preguntas puntuales, que se cierren (todavía tengo votos de cierre hoy).

Comment: @EmanuelVe estoy de acuerdo en que hay que seguir trabajando para ser referentes, mejorar seo, etc. Mi comentario, no iba por distraer del motivo principal, ni por _discutir sobre quien gano reputación "injusta"_, iba por la observación de **lo atractivo de ganar reputación sin trabajo** permitiendo esta iniciativa y comportamientos del tipo: _A ver que pregunto hoy... ¿Para que sirve la extensión `.html`?_ Por lo leído hasta ahora, va en contra de las propias instrucciones que están en la ayuda.

Comment: @toledano sí, se trata de establecer políticas generales. Puse estos ejemplos pues son los que más vi últimamente, pero no hice nada en ellos (ni di votos, ni solicité cerrar) hasta ver si logramos un consenso. Respecto la guía que enlazas, efectivamente es muy clara.

Comment: @EmanuelVe creo que el SEO es importantísimo, claro está. De todos modos, creo que estas preguntas serían mucho más útiles si el propio autor hiciera investigación previa y creará una respuesta wiki para que todos la mejoraran. Así como se están realizando ahora, se consiguen respuestas rápidas (¡si no corro otros contestarán antes y se llevarán puntos!) y el contenido queda difuso entre distintas respuestas.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/65

Comment: Tal y como comenta @Rubén, discusión relacionada: [Las preguntas deberían de mostrar esfuerzo e investigación por parte del autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/83).

Comment: Se ven muchos casos a menudo de preguntas solo para auto responderse, lo peor que la respuesta ya la tienen armada antes de hacer la pregunta, en muchos casos son copy past mal traducido con google translate de preguntas que fueron realizadas en ingles, otros casos son temas de poco sentido, que se autoresponden en menos de 3 segundos. La verdad lo veo como algo desleal ganar puntos por ese tipo de auto respuestas instantaneas.

Comment: @Ricardo nótese que contestarse a uno mismo es algo perfectamente válido y recomendado: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer). Fíjate además que en muchos casos se publica la respuesta en modo wiki de comunidad.

Answer (score 4):

Últimamente se ve mucho revuelo alrededor de este tema, y me gustaría participar. Entiendo que hay preguntas que aun sin que las respalde una investigación mínima, acaban convirtiéndose en interesantes, no por la pregunta en si misma, sino por las respuestas que obtiene. He visto como se han cerrado preguntas mediocres con unas respuestas interesantes tirando a la basura el trabajo de algunos usuarios de este sitio. No sé que tipo de criterio usan los moderadores para llevar acabo este tipo de cierres... Entiendo que es uno consensuado por todos los usuarios, o al menos por los usuarios del sitio en el momento en que se establecieron dichas normas. Personalmente entiendo que una respuesta (y por extensión, una pregunta) se vuelven interesantes cuando empiezan a recibir un determinado número de votos, y ya os digo que he visto cerrar algunas con un número considerable. Hay ya un buen número de usuarios "reclamando" poder hacer y responder a preguntas de este tipo ¿por qué no lo consideramos al menos?

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, Muriano. En cuanto a _se han cerrado preguntas mediocres con unas respuestas interesantes tirando a la basura el trabajo de algunos usuarios de este sitio_, si la pregunta no se borra, ese contenido sigue disponible y por tanto no se tira por la borda.

Comment: En cuanto a _No sé que tipo de criterio usan los moderadores para llevar acabo este tipo de cierres_, idealmente los moderadores no deberían participar, sino que es una cosa que hace la comunidad colectivamente. Lo que sí es cierto es que no estamos llegando a ningún consenso y lo que parece que es en Meta luego en la práctica no se cumple.

Comment: No coincido contigo en que el número de votos sea representativo ahora mismo. Hay contenido fantástico con pocos votos y otro muy normalito que sobresale. Observo cierta tendencia a votar lo que ya tiene votos, eso sí, y es normal: las preguntas más genéricas y googleables reciben visitas y votos. Sin embargo, apuesto por que [es.so] tenga ya Documentation para poder poner todas estas cuestiones "básicas" allí y centrarnos en preguntas realmente potentes.

Comment: A todo esto, mi pregunta aquí era sobre si es pertinente publicar una pregunta sin mostrar ningún tipo de esfuerzo en resolverla :)

Answer (score 2):

## Junio de 2019

No, no debemos permitirlas. Llevamos ya 2 años con el sitio graduado. Las preguntas básicas están ya casi todas respondidas.

Aún puede aparecer alguna nueva, por ejemplo sobre un nuevo lenguaje, biblioteca, etc. Pero permitirlas solo servirá para tener que malgastar tiempo marcando un 99% de preguntas básicas como duplicadas. Mejor establecer una regla sencilla, la del esfuerzo o trabajo de investigación, que permita cerrar or votar de forma ágil sin consultar nada más que la propia pregunta. Al otro 1% le queda la posibilidad de esforzarse algo más al redactar la pregunta, tampoco es un rechazo total. Y quien no quiere hacer ese esfuerzo tampoco ha de sorprenderse de que otros no se quieran esforzar para responderle.

## Junio de 2017

Hay que construir el edificio empezando por los cimientos, no por el tejado.

Todos empezamos con preguntas sobre conceptos básicos. Quien no encuentre la respuesta a eso la buscará en otro sitio. Y continuará usando ese otro sitio para preguntas progresivamente más avanzadas.

Rechazar las preguntas básicas sin esfuerzo es equivalente a rechazar a usuarios noveles. Con frecuencia el que pregunta no sabe ni por donde empezar.
No sirve argumentar que con una búsqueda se puede solventar esas preguntas básicas. Todas las preguntas se pueden solventar sin acudir a SO, al fin y al cabo el que escribió la respuesta por primera vez en SO lo hizo cuando ese conocimiento no estaba disponible en SO.

## Todos los días.

Independientemente de que se permitan o no hay algo que sí puedes hacer si quieres responder una pregunta de este tipo.

Abre otra pregunta sobre lo mismo. Antes de publicarla escribe también su respuesta.
Que sea autorespondida no cambia los criterios para cerrar la pregunta. Sigue teniendo que ser interesante, bien formulada, concreta, dentro del ámbito del sitio, útil, clara y con todos los elementos necesarios para responderla independientemente de si es autorrespondida o no.
Lo que sí que hace es desplazar el lugar en que se encuentra el esfuerzo y el trabajo de investigación. Es aceptable en las preguntas autorrespondidas que todo este esfuerzo e investigación esté en la autorespuesta y no exista en absoluto en la pregunta.

Comment: "paso a paso" decía mostaza merlo y lo saco campeón a Racing... osea.. a Racing... lease, esto recién empieza.

Comment: Entiendo y comparto tu punto en cuanto a que estamos construyendo los cimientos. Sin embargo, la parte de _Rechazar las preguntas básicas sin esfuerzo es equivalente a rechazar a usuarios noveles_ no. Yo nunca programé en Haskell, pero si algún día me pongo bucearé un rato en la documentación antes de preguntar como se hace un "echo" (o lo que tengan allí). Eso creo que es exigible al usuario. De hecho acabo de [leer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179039/209901): _The point of research effort isn't to say "I deserve an answer", it's to say "this question deserves to be here."_

Comment: @fedorqui, ¿cómo se evidencia el _"esfuerzo de investigación"_? Por ejemplo, afirmaciones del tipo _"ya busqué y no encuentro..."_ o _"leí pero no entiendo..."_. Personalmente, creo que he votado por cerrar muchas preguntas de este estilo. ¿Podrías proponer alguna sugerencia para eliminar (o al menos reducir) el componente subjetivo en _"this question deserves to be here"_? Mi intención es mejorar mi competencia al evaluar las preguntas, controlando el riesgo de votar falsos negativos.

Comment: @fedorqui es una posición razonable. Como punto intermedio he editado mi respuesta con una alternativa para que las preguntas sin esfuerzo sean cerradas pero sin impedir que el sitio se "siembre" con respuestas a cuestiones básicas.

Comment: Desacepto la respuesta pues veo que actualmente tiene +5 y -3. Dado que es un tema para el que estaría bien conseguir consenso, sigamos opinando y veamos qué piensa la gente.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la verdad en mi opinion es que ese tipo de usuarios no les veo un poco de esfuerzo en investigar ese tipo de preguntas basica con tan solo buscar en google esa pregunta te saldra miles de sitios web aparte de la documentacion oficial del lenguaje(en este paso PHP),o bibloteca al principio de la busqueda, pero en otra parte entiendo que son usuarios que estan iniciando en el mundo de la programacion en este caso PHP, nadie inicio en este mundo sabiendolo todo, todo pasamos por uno momento que otro usuarios en stackoverflow o otro sitio que nos critico igualmente porque nuestra pregunta es algo basica, pero en mi opinion y lo que yo siempre realizo cuando veo una pregunta asi,

NOTA(lo comento porque yo respondi una pregunta de las que comentas).

yo solo les contesto la respuesta y les doy un consejo de lo que deberian leer o ver.

y para terminar yo recomendaria que las preguntas basicas que las vuelven a preguntar sean cerradas y que algun moderador o usuario le comparte el link de la pregunta ya contestada.

Esta es solo mi opinion.

Comment: Es gracioso que digas eso cuando algunas de tus preguntas en Meta ni se ha buscado primero en el sitio..

Comment: esta bien amigo.

Comment: son preguntas básicas de poco sentido para usuarios avanzados, pero quisas para gente nueva que se adentra en tema de programación es algo interesantes, y aveces uno aprende cosas nuevas que habia pasado por alto de algo tan sencillo, aunque la idea del autor siempre sea ganar puntos facil, considero que hay que ser amplios al aceptar preguntas, mientras esten bien formuladas y aporten algo al contenido aunque sea algo que todos creemos saber.