# ¿Puedo crear una pregunta wiki de comunidad?

Tags: soporte, wiki-de-comunidad

Hasta donde he visto, solo las respuestas pueden ser convertidas a wiki de la comunidad.

Estaba interesado en abrir una wiki de la comunidad sobre validaciones regexp para que todo el mundo se valiera de ahí, pues no hay ninguna pregunta sobre este tema en general.

Me preguntaba cuál era la mejor forma de hacer esto. ¿Tengo que crear yo la pregunta, luego responderla y convertirla en wiki de la comunidad, o hay otra forma?

Comment: Véase https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? ¿Cómo convertir una pregunta a wiki de comunidad?

Comment: @fedorqui, si. Se puede? O son solo las respuestas?

Comment: Ya vi que no hay preguntas WC.   
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action/67582#67582

Comment: Las preguntas solo pueden ser marcadas como WC por los moderadores. Dado este hecho, lo razonable parece ser hacer la pregunta propia y la respuesta WC, que es al fin y al cabo lo que la gente andará modificando.

Comment: Me responderias la pregunta? , creo que algunos novatos como yo podrian tener la misma duda mas adelante, y les seria mas facil encontrar la solucion si es una respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no puedes crear una pregunta wiki de comunidad.

Tal y como se indica en [¿Qué es una publicación “Wiki de comunidad”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318/83):

> - Una respuesta publicada para una pregunta wiki también será wiki. **En el pasado las preguntas podían ser convertidas en wiki por sus autores o automáticamente cuando se cumplían ciertas condiciones, pero [ahora la única manera es la intervención de un moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940)**. Cuando un moderador convierte una pregunta en wiki de comunidad, todas las respuestas existentes se convierten también, y lo mismo ocurrirá con las respuestas publicadas con posterioridad.

Tal y como se ve en Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > [Crear Publicaciones Wiki](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), así es como marcas tu respuesta como *Wiki de Comunidad*:

[image: Wiki de comunidad]

---

Contesto ahora a cómo actuar en el caso que planteas. Ante todo: ¡muchas gracias por la idea y por las ganas de implementarla! Seguro que será de ayuda.

Yo lo que haría es crear una pregunta normal y corriente. Esto es, de calidad y útil (*interesante, bien formulada, concreta, dentro del ámbito del sitio, útil, clara y con todos los elementos necesarios para responderla independientemente de si es autorrespondida o no*, tal y como [indica](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2157/83) Jose Antonio Dura Olmos) . Al mismo tiempo, publicaría una respuesta wiki de comunidad con todo el contenido que fuera capaz de redactar, pero también de manera que otros especialistas en la materia se vieran animados a aportar sus conocimientos. Así se haría efectiva la parte *de comunidad* y esa respuesta sería cada vez más completa.