# Sobre la pregunta ¿Cómo iniciar aplicaciones de diversos tipos desde otra aplicación?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, respuesta-canónica, pregunta-autorespondida

El otro día, a raíz de esta pregunta [¿Cómo abrir aplicación instalada en Windows 10 desde VB.NET?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90933/15301)  en la que el OP no se explicó bien al principio y tuve que ir editando mi respuesta para adaptarla a sus requerimientos, me pareció buena idea tener una respuesta canónica sobre el tema y realicé la siguiente pregunta autorespondida
[¿Cómo iniciar aplicaciones de diversos tipos desde otra aplicación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90979/15301) para poder marcar como duplicadas las preguntas sobre ese tema en C#.

La pregunta ha acabado siendo puesta en espera como *no está claro lo que se pregunta* (aunque en mi opinión pudiera tratarse en todo caso de *demasiado amplia* en todo caso). Me gustaría saber que opináis, hay alguna manera de salvarla? Es mejor dividirla? O eliminarla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Las preguntas, aún las autorespondidas, deben seguir los lineamientos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

¿Dividirla? No hay mucho que dividir pues apenas son dos líneas.

¿Eliminarla? <s>Ni la pregunta ni la respuesta tienen votos positivos, si no reciben votos antes de seis meses serán eliminada automáticamente</s>.

## Explicación

### Buscar/Investigar

Agrega enlaces a preguntas similares, por ejemplo, el enlace a la pregunta que te motivó a escribir la pregunta.

### Contenido

> En [.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) existen varios tipos de aplicaciones/modos de instalación. ¿Cómo se puede ejecutar desde una aplicación .Net otra atendiendo a estos criterios?

#### Problema

1. "En [.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) existen varios tipos de aplicaciones/modos de instalación": Muy vago.

Solución: Lista los tipos de aplicaciones / modos de instalación.

2. "...a estos criterios": No se menciona ningún criterio.

Solución: Agrega los criterios.

3. Si lo anterior fuera demasiado extenso, y cada uno tuviera su propio modo de iniciar, enfoca la pregunta en uno de los tipos/modos de instalación.

### Título

Siendo el contenido tan breve y vago no hay mucho que resumir. No hay un problema específico.

## Preguntas en Meta relacioandas

- [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/65)

Comment: Un par de aclaraciones Ruben: La respuesta tiene un voto positivo ahora mismo,con lo que no será eliminada automáticamente en principio. Dividirla me refería a hacer una pregunta/respuesta para cada tipo de aplicación(ejecutables normales, instalaciones ClickOnce y aplicaciones UWP). Tienes razón en cuanto a que el planteamiento de la pregunta es un poco vago, trataré de editarla para concretarla un poco mas. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Ya taché lo de ningún voto. Sobre a que te referías, pues podría parecer obvio, pero decidí tomar literalmente la  pregunta en Meta, un poco para implicar que algunos compañeros, incluso yo mismo en ocasiones, somos "literalistas" (creo que algunos de los que votan para cerrar caen frecuentemente en ello) :)